# DC acting like AC

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I teach for a class that has to go over physics. We are by no means electricians and we need basic understandings but one of the questions that is being asked is this:

> Describe a way to get a DC supplied electromagnet to change the direction of the magnetic field, like the AC does.

Now I do not see how to display this in the virtual lab we use.  DC is one direction even when the current appears to go the opposite direction by switching the battery around the current is still traveling from the negative to the positive end of the battery.  So technically I do not see how the magnetic field can act like AC if the current direction never changes? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

rotate the electromagnet so its two poles switch position. its field is now reversed.